# Trouble installing Exchange 2010 on W2K8r2 .. please help :)

Tags: exchange-2010, installation

I'm trying to install MS Exchange 2010 (free TRIAL edition from MS) on a virtual pc running W2K8 r2. When I get upto the stage where it does the readiness checks, it fails. It's saying it can't find the default website on IIS or something.

[image]

I'm pretty sure i do have IIS installed....

[image]

and to test this ...

[image]

.
.
.

so .. can anyone help / make any suggestions?

NOTE: tools i'm using

- SUN Virtual Box (because MS VPC doesn't allow x64)
- W2K8 r2 x64 bit
- Exchange 2010 TRIAL edition

NOTE 2: I'm sure you can download a preinstalled VPC, etc. etc. but i'm trying to play around with the installation process, as opposed to the *using* process.

Comment: Curious: Are you using the "Administrator" account within the 2008 system? Not an account that has the rights, but the original Administrator account.

Comment: Yes I am. The default ADMIN account. I have no other accounts or users which i *manually* added.

Comment: Are you right-clicking the setup and choosing "Run as Administrator?"

Comment: Yep. sure did. In fact, I just did it again, just then .. to make tripple sure. :(

Comment: Did you reboot after installing IIS? What does the link in the recommended action tell you to do?

Comment: Yes I have and the link says 'go and install IIS'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps some optional feature of the IIS installation is needed, here's the stuff you need to [install before Exchange 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691354.aspx) - try going through them. Lots of different parts for IIS on a CAS role for instance the IIS6 management compatibility pieces I think:

```
Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server,Web-Basic-Auth,Web-Windows-Auth,Web-Metabase,Web-Net-Ext,Web-Lgcy-Mgmt-Console,WAS-Process-Model,RSAT-Web-Server,Web-ISAPI-Ext,Web-Digest-Auth,Web-Dyn-Compression,NET-HTTP-Activation,RPC-Over-HTTP-Proxy -Restart
```

Comment: I know i'm missing the IIS6 management stuff ... so that's an awesome suggestion. Also .. that link is WIKID! all those Powershell commands (like yours, above). i gotta try that :) i'll keep you posted ... and cheers mate :)

Comment: Wicked indeed, good luck! I'm not so sure this is the problem you're having but - we'll see I guess. Powershell is awesome for these kinds of things, it sure beats having to explain each step in a GUI tool, most likely needing a bunch of screenshots for each part, and just post a command instead ^^

Comment: +1 - the metabase is a seperate component to IIS. I know 2k7 used it, I'm surprised that 2k10 does as well!

Comment: cheers :) this got me past that screen, above. fully awesomesauce! thanks mate!!

Comment: I had the same problem the this fixed it for me